# Logstash- Windows 7

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I try to install logstash basis on this website:

https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash

When I call this comand:

```
logstash agent -f logstash.conf
```

in my CMD console, I get and error:

[image]

My bin file:

[image]

PS. I get similar error with .conf file. Both are empty.

Comment: If your config file is empty, it won't work, you need to specify input, filter and output in order for logstash to do something.

Comment: Can you support me with example? What does actually this command do?

Comment: Maybe you should first explain what you are trying to achieve, why you want to use logstash for and what use case you expect logstash to help you with.

Comment: I want to connect elasticSearch with AWS DynamoDB but I got an error: "Could not find a valid gem 'logstash-core' <<2.0.0, >= 1.4.0> in any resposotury'. First i need change my logstah version but how to add it to repository?

Comment: 1. You are seeming to call logstash.config instead of logstash.conf. And your file is named as logstash.config but not logstash.conf
2. Did you include any input, filter, output configuration in your conf file?

Comment: It's been quite time, did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Logstash comes with OpenJDK and fully packet all needed things. In the error message, seen that the error exist because of using system jvm and your jvm is not supported. Try to change your jdk to jdk8 or use installed OpenJDK of the logstash and check if your config file is ok.